# Nginx can't return 304 when using http proxy with ngx_http_sub_module

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

I want to reverse proxy the site www.gstatic.com with Nginx.

- Use site gstatic.178.re to reverse proxy www.gstatic.com
- Replace the content containing "www.gstaic.com" in the resource so further request can still be processed by "gstatic.178.re".

Basically it worked, while it won't return 304 if I access the same link again. I have enabled caching at Nginx and also tried to set etag and expires attributes.
Here's my Nginx configuration,

```
upstream gstatic { 
server www.gstatic.com; 
} 

proxy_buffering on; 
etag on; 
proxy_temp_file_write_size 1024k; 
proxy_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/temp; 
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_one:100m inactive=19d max_size=5g; 

server { 
listen 80; 

server_name gstatic.178.re; 

resolver 8.8.8.8; 

location / { 
sub_filter "www.gstatic.com" "gstatic.178.re"; 
sub_filter "https" "http"; 
sub_filter_once off; 
sub_filter_types *; 
proxy_pass_header Server; 
proxy_set_header Host www.gstatic.com; 
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ''; 
proxy_redirect off; 
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme; 
proxy_pass http://gstatic; 
proxy_cache cache_one; 
proxy_cache_valid 200 304 365d; 
proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args; 
proxy_cache_min_uses 1; 
expires max; 
proxy_cache_revalidate on; 
add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status; 
add_header Cache-Control "public"; 
if_modified_since before; 
} 


}
```

Here's one sample link for testing: http://gstatic.178.re/charts/loader.js

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted several problems in response headers of provided resource.
First you've violated one of [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) rules, which says:

> HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one
>      year in the future.

So try to reduce your max-age and Expires values to meet that requirement.

Second, you have no ETag in response headers.

Comment: I've tried to change expires  and max-age but still not work. I noticed comparing to normal 304 requests, these requests from browser do not send header:    " If-Modified-Since ".

Comment: Share please screenshot with headers